# if statement logic with OR condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, operators

I have to test a condition such that when the value of `dr["QUALITY"].ToString()` will not be "A" or the value of `dr["QUALITY"].ToString()` will not be "D" then only the if block should be executed. But the `if` block code is executed when the value is "A".

```
string test = dr["QUALITY"].ToString();
if ((!dr["QUALITY"].ToString().Equals("A")) || (!dr["QUALITY"].ToString().Equals("D")))
{
    dr["QUALITY_GRD"] = Calc_Rank(Convert.ToInt32(dr["QUALITY"].ToString()), 0);
    dr["QUALITY_PT"] = Calc_Grade(dr["QUALITY_GRD"].ToString(), 1);
}
else
{
    dr["QUALITY_GRD"] = "";
    dr["QUALITY_PT"] = "";
}
```

Here the `if` block code is executed when the value is "A". I can't understand what is the problem with the code. Please suggest. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your case when `QUALITY` is `"A"` then the second part of you `if`-statement

```
(!dr["QUALITY"].ToString().Equals("D"))
```

is true

so you code should look like this

```
string quality = dr["QUALITY"].ToString();
if (quality != "A" && quality != "D")
{
    dr["QUALITY_GRD"] = Calc_Rank(Convert.ToInt32(quality), 0);
    dr["QUALITY_PT"] = Calc_Grade(dr["QUALITY_GRD"].ToString(), 1);
}
else
{
    dr["QUALITY_GRD"] = "";
    dr["QUALITY_PT"] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

The code currently reads, if it's not `A` or it's not `D`.

So, if you pass it an `A` it still true, because it's not a `D`.

Answer (score 1):

Bug in your code is OR (||) comparison and two negate conditions. Check following pseudo-code:

```
If ( character is not A OR character is not D )
 => Always true.
```

So change comparison to this:

```
if ((!dr["QUALITY"].ToString().Equals("A")) && (!dr["QUALITY"].ToString().Equals("D")))
```